# SQLSRV statement returns false but doesnt say what the error is

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am executing a stored procedure using:

```
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);

    if ($stmt === false) {
        echo print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
        return null;
    }
```

`$stmt` is returning false but the echoed error message just says:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]1190 [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]1190 ) )

Every time I refresh the page, the number (1190 in above example) changes to something seemingly random.

Can anyone make sense of that error message?

Comment: How do you execute the stored procedure?

Comment: is it actually connected, what is the value of `$conn`

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you attempting to connect to? `ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server` is quite old, it only supports up to SQL Server 2014. Ref: [SQL version compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files#sql-version-compatibility)